# What functionality (if any) is associated with "Start Date" and "Target Date" fields in Features and Epics for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps with "Scrum" Process templates. I would like to know if "Start Date" and "Target Date" fields in Features and Epics are purely informational, or is there specific functionality associated with them?

If there is a functional aspect to these 2 fields, please explain where and how the fields are used in Azure DevOps. As an example, Iteration start and end dates are used to render the Feature Timeline of the Backlog Board, but I don't see any effect of a Feature's "Start Date" and "Target Date" fields on the Feature Timeline.

Comment: I really hoped for a connection between epic dates and feature dates, especially with functionalities like the delivery plans. The epic's target date for example should not be exceeded by any child feature. Users may receive a warning for example when setting the feature target date after the parent epic target date. I didn't find such a connection. If there is a possibility to configure it, I would appreciate a hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just the common fields for Epic and Feature work items. The Epic and Feature have different backlog levels with other work item types as defined in [Scrum process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process?view=azure-devops), and they will also render the project timeline.

> **Start Date** : The date and time when the schedule indicates that the epic/feature will start.
>
> **Target Date** : The date by which a epic/feature should be completed.

Se we can [Select backlog navigation levels for your team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/select-backlog-navigation-levels?view=azure-devops). Each team can determine the backlog levels that they use. For example, feature teams may want to only focus on their product backlog, while a management team may choose to only show feature and epics (the two default portfolio backlogs). You configure which backlog levels appear from your team settings dialog.

Generally we can simply know when Epics/Features must be started and delivered via a Start Date and Target Date to ensure they do not fall out of an iteration.

We can also query the specific Epics or Features by the fieldes. Please see [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops) for details.

Answer (score 0):

'Delivery Plan' provides a timeline view for project based on selected teams and backlog level. Delivery Plan uses start date and target date of work item types to generate this timeline. Drag of items card edges in Delivery Plan enables updating the dates. It's a handy features